# What does "it got twisted up" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, lyrics

I've [tried](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_plvOvyBik) to translate the lyrics of one of my favorite English-language songs into Croatian.
A part of the lyrics is: *The country that you died for, mate, you wouldn't know it now. The future that we dreamed of, mate, **got all twisted up** somehow.*

But what does *it got twisted up* mean? I looked it up in several dictionaries and I couldn't find it. I translated it as *izjalovila*, which is the word Croatians use for a plan that turned out to be impossible to realize. It rhymes in my translation, and I guess it's correct, but I am not sure.

What do you think?

Comment: What "got all twisted up" means is that the future didn't turn out the way they thought it would—instead, a "twisted" (and from context, clearly worse) version was realized. "Impossible to realize" is certainly a reasonable translation for it, especially if it rhymes.

Comment: 'Convoluted' is a very formal and more 'adjectivy' synonym, 'screwed up' less formal and more 'verby'.

Comment: Consider if you are riding a bicycle while wearing a scarf.  The scarf falls off and gets twisted up in the bike's rear wheel.  Before you can stop it's become twisted so badly that you can't untangle it -- you end up having to cut if off.

Comment: @PeterShor, I would be interested in how you came to know that? And what does 'up' mean in "twisted up"? Is it a part of a phrasal verb that needs to be memorized, or is there a meaning to it?

Comment: From the dictionary: [twisted](https://www.lexico.com/definition/twisted): Forced out of its natural or proper shape; crumpled. So metaphorically, it's not the proper future, not the one that we intended. As for *up*, there's a phrasal verb *twist up*, which means to make something twisted. But *twisted up* and *twisted* would mean the same thing here.